# Domain throwing server IP address could not be found

Tags: dns, centos, website

Yesterday my website was working pretty well. After a night sleep, my website now throws this error. "**server IP address could not be found.**". I simply can't figure out what happened to the website. I checked my domain provider and it is still linked to my hosting. I checked my hosting set-up but it was still the same. I don't know where to look anymore.

I am using a Centos Web Panel for my hosting. My site is http://sample.em-n-em.us

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I just got to it using 122.54.20.213, so your dns record is missing.

Comment: I tried adding it but still not responding

Comment: I cannot get to it using the url, but can with ip address, this means the dns record is missing.

Comment: Is there any way to check any problems in my hosting? I am really lost right now. Thanks

Comment: I have tried updating my DNS hoping it would work somehow but still the error persist

Comment: No DNS record is being returned (as far as I can tell) which likely implies a problem with the DNS server itself.

Comment: I can take several days for dns record updates to propagate through the dns system.

Comment: Did you ask your registrar or DNS provider for help? Domain `em-n-em.us` is severely misconfigured as you can see on DNSViz. You should not use two nameservers with only a single IP address, this makes no sense, and the two listed nameservers, only one in fact since only one IP is not configured to resolve the same `sample.em-n-em.us`. Hence this name has no IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Your domain has many problems (see my comment) but the first thing to solve is this, from whois:

```
$ whois em-n-em.us
Domain Name: em-n-em.us
Registry Domain ID: D27EB90CB8ED5482ABC634C2179941888-NSR
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.namecheap.com
Registrar URL: http://www.namecheap.com
Updated Date: 2019-10-30T01:31:14Z
Creation Date: 2018-10-24T05:58:38Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2020-10-24T05:58:38Z
Registrar: NameCheap, Inc.
Registrar IANA ID: 1068
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@namecheap.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.6613102107
Domain Status: serverHold https://icann.org/epp#serverHold
               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

`serverHold` means the registry has suspended your domain. It is not published on their authoritative nameservers and hence nothing in it will resolve.
See the link given for more information, but in general registries use this for abuse or disputes.

You will need either to ask the registry directly about this or go through your registrar.

Nothing will work until this status is removed from your domain.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am kinda still in the learning process of creating my own web server.  I just kinda did what was in the tutorials.

Comment: @marvincastro This is not a matter of following tutorials. Something else happened for the registry to put your domain in "serverHold", this is not common and does not happen without good reasons. Like I said you need to contact the registry directly or through your registrar to clarify the reason of that status (and as long it is kept attached to your domain, no website will ever work, no matter what you will do).

Comment: I have contacted the provider. They are going to contact Neustar Regsitry about this. Thanks again for the information. It helped me a lot. As to the reason why, I still don't know why it was put down. Will a suspicious script or hacking attempts be the cause of this?